# How to recompile program for .Net Framework 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010 and i was trying to create program based on .Net Framework 4 and when i done it, program was working only on my computer, coz nobody of my friends don't have .Net framework 4 installed.

How to recompile program for .Net Framework 3 in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: You just change the configuration properties to target your chosen the version of .net

Comment: I appreciate that Stack Overflow is a wonderful site, but web search still exists and you really ought to try that first. You'll be much more productive if you learn how to use web search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change project settings.
[image]

Or use command-line csc to compile

Answer (score 3):

right-click on the project `properties` and change `Target framework` from `.NET Framework 4` to `.NET Framework 3`

Answer (score 3):

Go to the *Project* menu

Click on the ***Your Project* Properties**

On the Application Tab, select **.NET Framework 3.5** from the Target Framework dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the target framework in Visual Studio 2010 between .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and 4.0.
See [How to: Target a Specific .NET Framework Version or Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) on MSDN.

As noted on that page, you might have to install 3.0 by hand since Visual Studio 2010 comes only with .NET 4.0.  But once you install 3.0, you will be able to target it.

Answer (score 0):

From the project in Visual Studio 2010, right click on the project and select Properties. Click on the Application tab, and from the Target Framework dropdown, select .NET Framework 3.0.

```
Project ->
Properties ->
Application (tab) ->
Target framework: .NET Framework 3.0
```

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) will help guide you with additional details.

And, not to be a schmuck, but you could have received a faster answer by [Googling](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=compile+program+for+.net+framework+3.0+visual+studio+2010#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=compile+.net+framework+3.0+visual+studio+2010&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=e51d8875f2782bc3) "compile .net framework 3.0 visual studio 2010" and noting that the first link is [How To: Change the Target .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).